# CSS to set background image fixed on android mobile phones?

Tags: android, css, image, background

I have set a fixed background image on my website and it looks fine on desktops and all browsers on desktop but on android phones it tiles and repeats it. I cannot find a work around this. Here is the code.. If someone has a fix for keeping a background image fixed without repeating on android Chrome please let me know.. thanks. Please exclude any comments that will not help.

the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/320htmlbackground.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;       
}
```

also tried this but didn't work.........

```
html { 
    background: url("images/320htmlbackground.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/320htmlbackground.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem but I'm not sure if it's the same one or not. My problem was that the background image wasn't staying in the same place as you would expect from a fixed image. I.e. when I scrolled up and down the background image moved with the page.

It turned out that I had set the background on the `body` tag. It worked fine on all browsers except on my phone. I changed the background to be on the `html` tag and it stays where it should without moving as I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works well:

```
body{
    position: relative;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```